# Swift: UICollectionView invalidateLayout not getting triggered

Tags: ios, swift2, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with a datasource and a layout class. The class is linked to the collection view in the Attributes Inspector.

By tapping buttons I need to retrieve data for the collection and this can mean different numbers of section/items. Therefore I need to restructure the layout each time. However this never seems to occur.

At the moment I have the following in the Success function for the data retrieval  request.

```
listingsView.reloadData()
listingsView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
listingsView.collectionViewLayout.prepareLayout()
```

I'm not sure that the prepareLayout is needed but tried it anyway. The datasource updates fine but the prepareLayout is never triggered by any of the lines.

Do I need some special settings or a different location for the invalidateLayout request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry - ignore this. Had a Boolean variable on layout that wasn't getting altered due to a forced return.

Just listingsView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() works fine.